# Comparing two Calendar dates with each other

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar

We've been trying to figure out how to compare two calendar dates in C# ASP.NET.

The problem we have is that when a customer uses the calendar, they can choose to set it back in time.

Example:

`2015-09-23 to 2015-08-23` <- this is something we don't want, it is set back in time.

How do we check if the start date is later than the end date.
We have seen someone using CDate? Which we did not understand how to use this.
We have tried to just remove the "-" from a string, convert it to an int and then calculate if the answer is less than 0.

But this was a big workaround. Is there an official or better way to do this?

If any more information is needed, feel free to ask!

Comment: check this link, you might find it helpful
http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/46343/date-ranges-from-a-given-start-date

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [CompareValidator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db330ayw(v=vs.71).aspx) in ASP.Net

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="myID" ControlToCompare="StartDate" 
         ControlToValidate="EndDate" Type="Date" Operator="GreaterThanEqual"   
         ErrorMessage="The dates are not correct." runat="server"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

or else

```
DateTime d1 = new DateTime(2015, 9, 1);
DateTime d2 = new DateTime(2015, 8, 2);
if (d1 < d2) 
{
   //error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy enough. I assume its only the date part you are interested in and not the time. The DateTime.CompareTo() method compares two dates and returns one of the following integer values:

```
-1 Less Than
 0 Equal To
 1 Greater Than
```

Using this and the Current Date we can easily tell if the given date is in the past. This method will take a date string, like the one provide in your example, and compare it to the current date (ignoring the time element) and return true if the given date is in the past, or false if it is equal to or greater than the current date.

```
    private bool IsDateInThePast(string inputDate)
    {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(inputDate);
        return dt.CompareTo(DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString())) < 0;
    }
```

Obviously, you might want to add some validation and/or exception handling to handle an invalid input string.